# If I set the number of bytes to receive to 2,147,483,647?

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, networking

I'm using the `Socket.BeginReceive` method to receive data asynchronously. What is going to happen if I set the size parameter (the amount of bytes to receive) to the int maximum value (2,147,483,647) and set the size of my byte array to 2,147,483,647 too??
How is this going to affect the performance?

Comment: Why not try it and find out.

Comment: I hope you'll have one connection

Comment: Because an effect will only show up when many clients are connected, and if I do so the client programs are going to affect my computer speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, according to

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxkwh6zw(v=vs.110).aspx

`Socket.BeginReceive` writes into `buffer` and thus `size` must be *equals or less* than `buffer.Length` otherwise you'll have `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` thrown:

```
 ArgumentOutOfRangeException
```

> offset is less than 0.
>
> -or- offset is greater than the length of buffer.
>
> -or- size is less than 0.
>
> -or-
>
> **size is greater than the length of buffer minus the value of the offset parameter.**

So you have to allocate an *enormous* (`2 GB`) array

```
  byte[] buffer = new byte[2147483647];
```

So if you're working on *64-bit .Net* and have *enough memory*, you're lucky; otherwise you'll have `OutOfMemoryException` thrown.

Conclusion: you're going to have *fearsome* memory overhead (`2 GB` per connection) and *negligible* performance gain. Do not do it, set `size` to reasonable value.